# fillna with a namedtuple or any other class pandas

Tags: python, pandas, namedtuple

Is there any way to fillna with a namedtuple in python?

I am getting this `TypeError`:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([0, 0, 0, 0, np.nan, 0, 0, 0])

nametup = namedtuple('mynp', ['arg1', 'arg2'])
q = nametup(None, None)
df.fillna(q)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-25-363ec560dd77>", line 9, in <module>
    df.fillna(q)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2762, in fillna
    downcast=downcast, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3101, in fillna
    'you passed a "{0}"'.format(type(value).__name__))
TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar or dict, but you passed a "mynp"
```

also tried this:

```
df.replace(np.nan, q)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-31-6f8a86f11bbb>", line 1, in <module>
    df.replace(np.nan, q)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3440, in replace
    raise TypeError(msg)  # pragma: no cover
TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'float'
```

any workaround? thanks!

Comment: Just as a warning, non-scalar entries aren't really supported by pandas and so you're going to be at risk of unexpected bugs.  Sometimes it's useful despite this, but I've actually been bitten by some in the past.

Comment: @DSM thanks for insight, will take a look if I can use another approach. Its just so convenient when you have classes by dates to use pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easy, but need create `Series` by objects and then replace `NaN`:

```
nametup = namedtuple('mynp', ['arg1', 'arg2'])
q = nametup(None, None)

s = pd.Series([q]*len(df.index))
print (s)
0    (None, None)
1    (None, None)
2    (None, None)
3    (None, None)
4    (None, None)
5    (None, None)
6    (None, None)
7    (None, None)
dtype: object
```

Solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df[0] = df[0].mask(df[0].isnull(), s)
print (df)
              0
0             0
1             0
2             0
3             0
4  (None, None)
5             0
6             0
7             0
```

Another solution with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by `Series` `s`:

```
df[0] = df[0].combine_first(s)
#similar solution
#df[0] = df[0].fillna(s)
print (df)
              0
0             0
1             0
2             0
3             0
4  (None, None)
5             0
6             0
7             0
```

Comment: Btw, this approach works if need replace `NaN` to empty lists